# Cursors.WaitCursor works only if Messagebox.Show is available

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am using C# .NET compact framework v3.5 on my windows mobile device and i use vs2008 for development.

I am experiencing an strange error  recently ,

This part of code `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;` is not working. i.e Wait cursor is not displaying

But when is use :

```
Messagebox.Show("");
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

I am getting the wait cursor

Is anything blocking `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;` from displaying ???

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the rest of the code you have. The system will only switch to the wait cursor if the UI thread can handle window messages. If the code that follows `Cursor.Current = ...` blocks the UI thread, you will not see any change.

I don't know why a `MessageBox.Show("");` should help there, but you can try this:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Application.DoEvents();
```

This lets the application process pending windows messages. It should thus also visually switch to the wait cursor.

Comment: No even Application.DoEvents(); is not working . What would be the other possible cases ??

Comment: I recently upgraded my compact framework from v2.0 to v3.5 . Should that cause any problems ??

Comment: I actually never experienced such problems. Only if just a very short period of time passes between switching to wait cursor and back, you will not see that the cursor changes.

Comment: No thats not the case . Because i have kept breakpoint in the next line and checked it .